# Sort by closest date, then past

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an art gallery page featuring a panel that shows up to 5 exhibitions 'At this gallery'. Sometimes there could be many on, it should show the current or upcoming first, then resort to past exhibitions.

Is it possible to do in one query?

The following will give me those closest in terms of date difference but I can end up getting past events at the top of the list  (because if it's a day past, it's obviously less than the upcoming event in 5 days)

```
SELECT   DATEDIFF(date_start, NOW()) as date_diff, exhibitions.*
FROM     events 
WHERE    event.gallery_id = XX
ORDER BY date_diff asc
LIMIT    5
```

Comment: How about just ordering by start_date desc?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The date_diff is returning negative values for past events.  This is one fix:

```
SELECT   DATEDIFF(date_start, NOW()) as date_diff, exhibitions.*
FROM     events 
WHERE    event.gallery_id = XX
ORDER BY (case when date_diff < 0 then 1 else 0 end),
         abs(date_diff) asc
LIMIT    5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order by `date_start < CURDATE()` which will return either 0 or 1, 0 being future, 1 being past, and if you order the result ASC then it would ensure future ones always show up before past ones

for example:

```
ORDER BY
  (date_start < CURDATE()) ASC,
  (greatest(date_start, CURDATE()) ASC,
  (least(date_start, CURDATE()) DESC
```

first one ranks future before past, second one orders the future ASC (closest first), third one orders the past DESC (oldest first)

(second and third ones are interchange)

Answer (score -1):

Normally you cant sort one column in both directions. If you want yo order by upcoming ASC the past DESC you can do it with trick:

```
SELECT yourDateColumn,IF(yourDateColumn)<NOW(),DATEDIFF(yourDateColumn),NOW()) * -1000000000,UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONVERT_TZ(e.startDate,e.timeZone,'Europe/Paris'), '%Y-%m-%d'))) AS diff FROM yourTable ORDER BY DIFF ASC;
```